# The / and /usr merge not implemented in my Ubuntu?

Tags: filesystem

Reading through systemd docs I came across [TheCaseForTheUsrMerge](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/).

The discussion about this topic dates from around 2012 AFAIK, and the opinion then was that all major distribution would incorporate this change anytime soon.

However, on my Ubuntu installation this is still not the case. Are there good reasons why this didn't happen?

Comment: Not really an answer, but usrmerge just landed in Xenial package archive: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usrmerge